# Microsoft Bot Framework won't send multiline messages

Tags: string, botframework, line-breaks

So I've built this bot that should respond to it's user with status messages. I want to make these messages rather clean and therefore wanted to start each new property with a new line. Only problem is that when I do this, the bot just prints the first few lines.

So this is the code I've got, I've made sure that the data is actually there.

```
 internal static string DeviceInformation(Device device)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append($"[Name]: {device.Name}\n\n");
            sb.Append($"[Location]: {device.LocationName} \n\n");
            if (device.ContactLost)
            {
                sb.Append("[Status]:Offline!\n\n");
                sb.Append($"[Time Offline]: {device.ContactLostTime} \n\n");
                sb.Append($"[Time Offline]: {device.ContactLostTime} \n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("[Status]:online! \n\n");
            }


            return sb.ToString();
        }

        internal static string DeviceInformation(Device device, DeviceHistory statistic)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(DeviceInformation(device));
            sb.Append($"[Time]: {statistic.CreatedTimeStamp} \n\n");
            sb.Append($"[Signal]: {statistic.SignalStrength} \n\n");
            sb.Append($"[Battery]: {statistic.BatteryLevel} \n\n");
            Debug.WriteLine("TOSTRING " + sb.ToString());
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

The next last line prints out this:

```
TOSTRING [Name]: Restroom 1

[Location]: Floor 2 

[Status]:online! 

[Time]: 16/05/2017 22:23:45 

[Signal]: -88 

[Battery]: 60
```

Now the bot just prints:

```
[Name]: Restroom 1
[Location]: Floor 2
[Time]: 16/05/2017 22:23:45
```

If I remove all the linebreaks `\n` and put everything on the same row, the bot prints the whole message.

Anyone having any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: Which messenger is the bot located in?

Comment: I have tried it in both the Bot Emulator and deployed on a channel on Slack. The result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting behavior. I was able to reproduce it... I'm still looking for the root cause of the issue, however, I found a workaround for you, that is using bullets.

I updated your code in the following way:

```
internal static string DeviceInformation(Device device)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append($"• [Name]: {device.Name}\n\n");
    sb.Append($"• [Location]: {device.LocationName}\n\n");
    if (device.ContactLost)
    {
        sb.Append("[Status]:Offline!\n\n");
        sb.Append($"[Time Offline]: {device.ContactLostTime}\n\n");
        sb.Append($"[Time Offline]: {device.ContactLostTime}\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append("• [Status]:online!\n\n");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

internal static string DeviceInformation(Device device, DeviceHistory statistic)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(DeviceInformation(device));
    sb.Append($"• [Time]: {statistic.CreatedTimeStamp}\n\n");
    sb.Append($"• [Signal]: {statistic.SignalStrength}\n\n");
    sb.Append($"• [Battery]: {statistic.BatteryLevel}\n\n");
    Debug.WriteLine("TOSTRING " + sb.ToString());
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

With that, it's working as expected in the emulator:

[image]